# Lazy image loading with Official Blogger lightbox widget

Tags: javascript, blogger

Google Blogger displays the images inside the post page with the lightbox gallery when clicked.
You can see an example at:
`https://googlereader.blogspot.com/2011/10/new-in-reader-fresh-design-and-google.html`

It works automatically when the source html code is as follows:

```html
<div class="separator">
    <a href="//example.com/image.png">
        <img src="//example.com/image.png" width="400" height="300" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

JavaScript events are defined at:
`https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3271249078-widgets.js`

I want to lazy load images.

```html
<div class="separator">
    <a href="//example.com/image.png">
        <img src="//example.com/loading.svg" width="400" height="300" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

The lightbox does not work when the link address ( `<a href="URL">` ) and the source of the image ( `<img src="URL" />` ) are different. I don't want to use extra css and js libraries. Can I manually assign the default lightbox gallery events with JavaScript without depending on the source of the image?

3271249078-widgets.js:75:24

```js
function a(c){return b.call(a.src,a.listener,c)
```